# /var/log/account/pacct is getting too big, where is ckpacct (to cicle/gzip it)?

Tags: disk-usage

I got 2 big files at, `/var/log/account`, of 350MB each..., my root is only 10GB...

I read there could have `ckpacct` to cycle and gzip it, but I cant find it, also no alternative command?

**EDIT**: I found that `sudo accton off` disable the logging but the files remain there, and I guess my next boot it will be activated again...

They seem to are being cycled but who actually does it?

```
369114432 May 13 23:23 /var/log/account/pacct
333708160 May 13 12:27 /var/log/account/pacct.0
 13681065 May 12 16:21 /var/log/account/pacct.1.gz
  3371433 May 11 09:50 /var/log/account/pacct.2.gz
  7549333 May 10 07:35 /var/log/account/pacct.3.gz
```

**EDIT**: my guess boot scripts does the cycle... anyway, I created this script, **but I dont know what safety implications it may have.. any considerations?**

`cat >ckpacct.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
  echo "there is no parameters and no --help, read the script and understand what is does, before running it up."
  exit 1
fi

if [[ "$USER" != "root" ]]; then
    echo "you must be root to run it..."
    exit 1
fi

function FUNCerror() {
    if(($1!=0));then exit 1; fi
}

cd /var/log/account;FUNCerror $? || exit

# fast ungrab pacct file
accton off;FUNCerror $?

mv -v pacct pacct.0.temp;FUNCerror $?

echo -n |tee pacct;FUNCerror $?
chown -v root:adm pacct;FUNCerror $?
chmod -v o-r pacct;FUNCerror $?

accton on;FUNCerror $?

# compress old 0
gzip -v --best pacct.0;FUNCerror $? #releases also pacct.0 filename

mv -v pacct.0.temp pacct.0;FUNCerror $? #restore new 0 from temp

# change file names upping indexes
#mv -v pacct pacct.0
for((i=4;i>=0;i--));do
    mv -v pacct.$i.gz pacct.$((i+1)).gz;FUNCerror $?
done
rm -v pacct.5.gz;FUNCerror $? # remove last in the limit
```

Comment: You got the index value as single integer, that's great but mine the index is a date, so I couldn't use this script.

Answer (score 2):

The script that cycles the logs is in `/etc/cron.daily/acct`. The number of log files is controlled by `/etc/default/acct`, which also controls whether process accounting should be enabled at boot time.

If you want to entirely remove process accounting, `sudo apt-get purge acct` should do the trick too.

Comment: With systemd you can also use `systemctl` to just `stop` and/or `disable` `acct.service`. [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-varaccountpacct-or-varlogaccountpacct-file/) more about acct.

Answer (score 1):

Get the acct cron to `cron.hourly` instead of daily. Then, put this values in `/etc/default/acct`:

```sh
ACCT_ENABLE="1"

# Amount of days that the logs are kept.
ACCT_LOGGING="2" # you cannot set this less than 2 
                 # if you don't want acct to get an error
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but since it wasn't answered...

I would assume that logrotate is doing your log rotation.  Check your crontab ("crontab -l") for a logrotate task that identifies the conf file.  Look in that conf file for details related to /var/log/account/pacct.

I didn't read your script closely, but it seems like your duplicating what logrotate does - no?

Comment: My `crontab -l` for normal user and root user both are empty :(. As I remember, the automatic log rotation seems to happen on every boot and are related to file date and not file size, so I need a solution engineered towards disk space :)

Comment: I created a config file for logrotate that worked, but it only run once and it deletes the original log file what forces me to recreate it zeroed. Basically I would need to put this in a loop: `accton off;logrotate lracct.cfg;echo -n |tee /var/log/account/pacct;accton on`, or add to crontab in someway I guess (never used crontab).

Comment: Sorry - just seeing your responses, but yes, you'd need to add it to a crontab.  You can configure logrotate to store more than one old version of the log, and logrotate should handle "pausing" accton while it rotates the logfile.  And is the "echo -n | tee" in your example basically doing a "touch" of the file?  That might be slightly clearer (if you decided to go that route).