# Is there better way for acct logrotaton or an alternative to the tool itself?

Tags: process, log, accounts

Hello I have a similar problem as discussed in [/var/log/account/pacct is getting too big, where is ckpacct (to cicle/gzip it)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295080/var-log-account-pacct-is-getting-too-big-where-is-ckpacct-to-cicle-gzip-it)

While the problem exists it would be preferable to compress the logs hourly instead of daily. I put a workaround in place with the following commands:

```
# Keep the same amount of log data: 30 days * 24 hours = 720.
sudo sed -i -e 's/\(ACCT_LOGGING=\)\("30"\)/#\1\2\n\1"720"/' /etc/default/acct

# Execute logrotate hourly instead of daily.
sudo mv -v /etc/cron.daily/acct /etc/cron.hourly/
```

That works, so far so good. But, uh this feels very clunky. I could go further to deny package updates to create the file again or pin the package, but it begs the **question: Someone else has probably seen this and come up with a more modern solution to the hacks and hard coded values from 20 years ago found in the [acct](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=acct) package** and I'm just making it worse by adding more shell code and moving files.

Comment: The general method would be to use logrotate. This is a tool that can manage any log file. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/437592/how-to-prevent-logs-from-getting-too-big

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes I do prefer logrotate, which is why I wrote one of the answers. It seems that the people involved with acct in around 2000 did not get feedback from the logrotate people and had to do something else. There is a comment in one of the scripts.